# Is "Lifetime" restriction implemented in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm watching CppCon 2015's talk [Writing Good C++14... By Default](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA) by Herb Sutter, he's referring to some lifetime restrictions, e.g.:

```
template<class Key, class T, /*...*/> class map {
iterator insert(const_iterator pos[[lifetime(this)]], const value_type&);
template <class InIter> void insert(InIter first, InIter last [[lifetime(first)]]);
// ...
};
```

so that

```
map<int,string> m = {{1,"one"}, {2,"two"}}, m2;
m.insert(m2.begin(), {3,"three"});// ERROR, m2.begin() points to m2, not m
m.insert(m.begin(), {3,"three"});// ok, m.begin() points to m
m.insert(m.begin(), m.end()));// 2 ERRORS: (a) params point to m, and (b) m is modifiable by m.insert
m.insert(m2.begin(), m.end()));// ERROR, param1 points to m2, but param2 points to m
m.insert(m2.begin(), m2.end());// ok, params point to m2, m2 not modifiable by m.insert
```

I'm wondering, is this "lifetime" an implemented feature already, or it's still in the wishlist?

Comment: Oh god, C++ draft committee, make it stop, *make it stop*. All these attributes... they're like the hashtags of code; or the C++ draft equivalent of "ah, screw it, let's just call it a day and go hit the pub".

Comment: So it's only in proposal stage for now, right? @JasonC

Comment: It doesn't seem to appear in [the list of standard attributes in cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), but IDK how definitive that is.

Comment: @athos Dunno. I've never seen that one, and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes doesn't list it as a standard attribute, although there are folks who don't particularly trust that site for various reasons. So I'm just assuming it's either in some draft somewhere, or used to be but wasn't approved, but I very well could be wrong about that. All I know is C++ gets a little weirder every couple of years.

Comment: C'mon, guys! That talk is about the C++ Core Guidelines and the associated static analysis, not the international standard!

Comment: For [tag:Rust] lifetime is part of the type :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sutter's talk is about the **C++ Core Guidelines**, **not** the International Standard of C++. The International Standard, created and maintained under ISO process, is a international treaty that serve as *the* definition of C++. The C++ Core Guidelines is not really part of C++, but rather a *community effort to describe how to use C++ well*.

The C++ Core Guidelines defines a set of guidelines on code quality and safety (including lifetime safety). It also defines a supporting library, a minimal set of in-code annotation (using attribute, type alias etc.), and static analysis to enforce the guidelines.

In the original question, there is no mention that whether this question is about the International Standard, the C++ Core Guidelines, mainstream compilers, or relevant static analysis tools. It is also unclear whether the premises of this question include the awareness of the distinction between these four things.

As of this writing, the C++ Core Guidelines is still evolving. The section of lifetime safety profiling is still left blank. Likewise, the static analysis tools are also evolving. [Microsoft's C++ Core Guidelines Checkers already has a preview of lifetime safety checker.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/c-core-guidelines-checkers-preview-of-the-lifetime-safety-checker/) [Clang-Tidy does not have lifetime safety check for now.](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html) But future development is expected and this paragraph will be therefore obsolete.

It is possible that individual compiler venders may decide to incorporate elements of the Guidelines into the compilation process. But it is really up to the compiler venders, and some guidelines may not be suitable to be enforce during compilation process. Similarly, some elements of the Guidelines may be proposed for standardization in future, but a lot of them are not suitable to be a part of the International Standard and better left as community guidelines.

Comment: I thought it's clear that this "lifetime" must be a language feature that requires compiler to digest.